# Target .NET 4.0 from Windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I need to target .NET 4.0 from my current Windows 10 development machine.

I can't find any offline installations of .NET 4.0 SDK. Right now I'm having 4.6.1 and 4.5.1 SDK installed, I've manually set 4.0 version in my csproj.

MSBuild gives me a warning that I need to install .NET 4.0 SDK and the compiler generates calls to System.Array.Empty (this call is generated by the compiler I don't use it directly) which doesn't exist on .NET prior to 4.6.

How do I make sure that I compile executables that would run on .NET 4.0 version (without System.Array.Empty and other stuff that doesn't exist in .NET 4.0)? Where do I get offline installer for .NET 4.0 SDK?

PS: I'm using JetBrains Rider and MSBuild 14.0 currently.  Alternatively. is there a way to make Roslyn not omitting `System.Array.Empty` calls for every empty array instantiation in my code?

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place? The earliest supported version is 4.5.2 and newer 4.x versions are binary replacements of older ones. This means that your machine will use a newer runtime no matter what you install. The customer PCs will probably have newer versions simply because of Windows Update patches. No supported OS requires .NET 4.0 either.

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207288089-Using-Project-Rider-under-Windows-without-Visual-Studio-prerequisites)

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the question doesn't ask how to set up Rider in general, it asks where to find the .NET 4.0 SDK, an unsupported version

Comment: The **only** reason to target 4.0 is because the application needs to run on Windows XP, which is also long past its end of support. Is this the case ? If not, there's no reason to target an unsupported runtime

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is the case. I tried installing Windows 7 SDK (that contains .NET 4.0 SDK in it), but it didn't work either.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that's the web installer, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718 that is the offline installer

Comment: My installation of VS 2017 can target .NET 4 with no problem, after checking support for that in the installer. Of course that's 1) VS and 2) not offline, but at least it's an officially supported solution. (I did not verify if the resulting assembly will actually load on XP -- it should, but since XP is no longer supported there's technically no requirement that it will.) In VS, the compiler's use of `Array.Empty` is dictated entirely by the target framework; the version of C# used has no effect on it.

Comment: "MSBuild gives me a warning that I need to install .NET 4.0 SDK and the compiler generates calls to System.Array.Empty (this call is generated by the compiler I don't use it directly) which doesn't exist on .NET prior to 4.6" indicates that you are using the wrong toolset. You are supposed to use the MSBuild from .NET Framework 4.0 installation folder, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-msbuild-cc72a217fa98

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually ended up installing Visual Studio 2013 along side with JetBrains Rider and it installed .NET 4.0 SDK as well as tone other stuff that I don't use. But now everything works as it should.